# Java reuse generic FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, fxml

I have some generic FXML with lots of components but lets say it is a textArea for simplicity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>


<TextArea fx:id="test" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" promptText="test data" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.101" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

And on this textArea you can see that it has an id of "test".

*So my question is can you could reuse this FXML in more than **one** controller?*

My initial thought was through an Generic Controller as seen below:

```
public abstract class GenericController {
    Program program = Program.getInstance();
    @FXML TextArea test;


    @FXML
    abstract void  initialize();
    abstract void setData();




}
```

And point the FXML to the **GenericController**.
And then **extend** it in a more specific controller. But i just get an LoadExceptionError which errors at the **fx:controller="sample.Controllers.GenericController"**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't specify the controller in the FXML file, i.e. remove the `fx:controller` attribute entirely. Then set the controller when you load the FXML:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/generic.fxml"));
GenericController controller = new SpecificControllerImplementation();
loader.setController(controller);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

Comment: There are more advanced things you can do using a controller factory, (which, for example, you could combine with a dependency injection framework) if you need, but it sounds like this would be enough for what you need.

Comment: Just tried this and i am still getting `javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.`

Comment: @audittxl Then you are doing something wrong. You're calling the no-argument `load()` method, right, not the static `load(URL)` method?

Comment: my mistake i did not compile the code **doh**! And ran the old code!

Comment: i am now getting a javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader error?!

Comment: @audittxl Again, that means you are doing something wrong (maybe `FXMLLoader.load(...)` instead of `new FXMLLoader(...)`). Use the code I posted, not some garbled version of it.

Comment: you are a genius!